# Unable to access userdefaults

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I have created a preference pane for my app. I am storing some basic settings into userdefaults using preference pane. I am not able to access these settings values from the application.

Am saving settings to user defaults as mentioned below:

```
NSString *fooBar = @"settings_value";
NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDef setObject:fooBar forKey:@"app_setting"];
[userDef synchronize];
```

Now when I access it from the app as :

```
NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *svcEnv = [userDef objectForKey:@"app_setting"];
```

I get a nil value. But when accessed from the preference pane project I will get the settings values but not in the application.

How can I retrieve settings value in the application ?

Comment: are you sure, that you have called saving method at least once?

Comment: @etolstoy Do you mean `synchronize` ? Yes I have done that. I can still read the values from the Preference Pane but not from the application. Its not sandboxed also.

Comment: Have you tried to log the value after sync..

NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"app_setting"]);

Answer (score 1):

[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] returns the defaults for the current application which in the case of a preference pane is the System Preferences application. Instead you need to use the preferences for the domain that has the bundle identifier for the bundle that contains the class of your preference pane:

```
NSUserDefaults *suds = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString * bundleID = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] bundleIdentifier];

NSMutableDictionary *prefs = [[suds persistentDomainForName:bundleID] mutableCopy];
```

To save them back use:

```
[suds setPersistentDomain:prefs forName:bundleID];
[sud synchronize];
```

Comment: I tried with this. I made sure both apps have the same bundle Identifier. And then I modified the part where I was saving from the Preferences Pane app to use its Bundle identifier as you have mentioned, but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `stringForKey:`

```
NSString *svcEnv = [userDef stringForKey:@"app_setting"];
```